# DHCP option to control interface metric

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing, dhcp

For some reason Windows is using only one interface for local network broadcasting (the one with lowest metrics). When client connects to VPN network, i want it to make new network preferred for broadcasting by changing metric value for 255.255.255.255 route on the  interface. Microsoft has a DHCP option that helps tweaking interface metric: Default Router Metric Base (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc227277.aspx). However, i can't make it working.

Client is running Windows 8, but similar problem exists on Windows 7 (can't say for earlier versions, although it must be present, as Windows identifies itself as "MSFT 5.0" since Windows 2000). Server is ISC DHCP Server 4.2 (isc-dhcp42-server-4.2.4_2). Client connects to the  server through  OpenVPN tunnel and receives DHCP information. According to Wireshark capture vendor specific options are sent as well. But it does not make any difference, table is identical to the one without that vendor option being sent.

Here is DHCP config:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;

log-facility local7;

option space ms-specific;
option ms-specific.metric-fix code 3 = unsigned integer 32;

subnet 172.16.130.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
{
  range 172.16.130.80 172.16.130.130;
  option routers 172.16.130.8;
  option broadcast-address 172.16.130.255;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  vendor-option-space ms-specific;
  option ms-specific.metric-fix 1;
}
```

Here is client's routing table after connecting

```
         Address          Mask            Gateway        Interface    Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.16.13.8     172.16.13.80     20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.130.8    172.16.130.80     30
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      172.16.13.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      172.16.13.80    276
     172.16.13.80  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.13.80    276
    172.16.13.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.13.80    276
     172.16.130.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     172.16.130.80    286
    172.16.130.80  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.16.130.80    286
   172.16.130.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.16.130.80    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.16.13.80    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.16.130.80    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.13.80    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.16.130.80    286
```

172.16.13.0/24 is physical local network. 172.16.130.0/24 is VPN. As you can see, routes from physical local network have lower metric. I believe it should be possible to prioritize VPN because Hamachi, for example, also creates virtual interface with 'Automatic metric' turned on, but after connecting it always has lower metric than both physical network and OpenVPN tunnel. I tried changing adapter order in 'Advanced settings' in 'ncpa.cpl', but it also had no effect.

So, is there any way to make my OpenVPN tunnel preferred for 255.255.255.255 broadcasting? It would be excellent if i can do it on server side, so clients do not have to  adjust anything.

Comment: Microsoft NetBios name resolution is broadcast based, I did a test (windows 7) few moments ago to test name resolution in physical and VPN segment. In both cases I've received an answer.